# Android fondo de 2 colores

Tags: android, android-studio

he creado un fondo a 2 colores pero en este caso me divide 50% de un color y 50% del otro este es el código:

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:centerX="0"
            android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

lo que yo busco hacer es que pueda modificar el porcentaje de color predominante no lo se un 70% y  30% o el que sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir un gradiente linear con un angulo de 270 grados y definir el centro al 70%

Este es un ejemplo, el 70% lo tiene el color verde (`startColor`), y el 30% lo tendría el color rojo (`endColor`), podrías definir un color transparente como `centerColor`, en este ejemplo se definio el color negro.:

```
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="70%" 
android:startColor="#00FF00" 
android:centerColor="#000000" 
android:endColor="#FF0000" 
android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: woow perfecto me funciono

Comment: Excelente, saludos. @bryanibarraalonso